# Should I use natural decking oil on a dark wooden deck?

Tags: decking

I have some decking with a fairly dark looking wood (please see photo), although it hasn't been cleaned yet so may be lighter than it appears.

I need to clean and oil this deck and I already have some Ronseal Ultimate Protection Decking Oil in Natural colour which someone gave me. Here's a link to the product: https://www.ronseal.com/for-garden/decking/decking-oil/ultimate-protection-decking-oil/

I prefer the darker look of decking, but could also do with saving a bit of money.

Given that the decking appears to be a little dark, can you describe what it's likely to turn out like with the natural colour oil?

I'm worried it will come out looking strange, because the decking colour and oil aren't compatible. Would that be the case?

Thank you in advance!

[image: Decking]

Comment: This will be difficult to answer. Your best bet would be to pressure clean the deck and then test the oil on a small. hidden section of the deck to see if it will satisfy  your desired appearance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see what it will look like with the oil finish applied, clean an inconspicuous area and put a bit of it on. Alternatively, untinted wood finishes often give the same appearance as the look when the wood is wet; clean an area and get it wet for a reasonable facsimile.

I would use what I had in hand anyway, because free is good, and natural weathering/graying will occur soon and your color choice can be changed next season (or the year after) if you prefer a finish with a dark tint.